# Angular Can get data from one json file but not a seperate one?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I've now changed out the names of the previous to the current names. Any help or ideas is much appriciated! The json file is provided so i don't use anything really, it's still works

Note: I have not created a service file as i'm not sure if it's needed or not.

This is the code I have:

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

    public countries: any;
    public displayedColumns: string[] = ['Code', 'Name'];

    constructor
    (
        public httpClient: HttpClient
    )
    {






}
```

App module. ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app component html

```
<div style="text-align:left;width:500px;">
  <h1>
      Tables with data
  </h1>

  <table *ngIf="countries">
      <!-- ADD HEADERS -->
      <tr>
        <th>c</th>
            <th>N</th>
            <th>C</th>
      </tr>

      <!-- BIND ARRAY TO TABLE -->
      <tr">
        <td>{{c}}</td>
        <td>{{n}}</td>
        <td>{{C}}</td>  
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: why do you need  this.countries = countries as string [];? i means specifically as a string []; ? try removing that.

Comment: Hey, removing that line does not work

Comment: Yeah, that should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `json` file is an object with a `Country` poperty but your code is expecting to receive an array.

Therefore you can reformat your`json` file to be an array of countries instead ...

Notice that I also typed your `countries` property with an interface instead of `any` and specify the type in `httpClient.get<T>` templated method.

StackBlitz example available here for the code represented below: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-52895400

> StackBlitz alternate example if you want to handle multiple properties in your json file: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-52895400-alt

**countries.json**

```
[
  {
    "Code": "ALB",
    "Name": "Albania",
    "Continent": "Europe"
  },
  {
    "Code": "ARG",
    "Name": "Argentina",
    "Continent": "South America"
  },
  {
    "Code": "BEL",
    "Name": "Belgium",
    "Continent": "Europe"
  }
]
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

export interface Country {
  Code: string;
  Name: string;
  Continent: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  public countries: Country[];

  constructor(
    public httpClient: HttpClient
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.httpClient.get<Country[]>('../assets/data/countries.json').subscribe(
      countries => {
        this.countries = countries;
        console.log(this.countries);
      },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log(err.message);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh wow this def works, what if there are multiple objects inside the json file? Like if the json file has multiple properties?

Comment: You would need to type with an interface representation of the return object in the `httpClient.get<T>` method and assign your component property according to the return object as desired. Typescript is here to help you know your object definitions so you dont make assomptions (use it as much as you can).

Comment: Hm I don't quite get what ur saying, do you think you could provide me with an example?

Comment: I've added an alternative StackBlitz example in the answer if you want to handle multiple properties in the json file.